# jq skip the initial invalid string before every json objects and print the selected column

Tags: json, logging, kibana, jq, cloud-foundry

We are formatting our logs into structured logs(json) so that it's easy to ingest and process logs by ELK.
but with that every time we need to go to Kibana to see the logs whereas on the app console (Cloudfoundry console) the logs are not human readable.
The logs printed as series of below string:
cf logs <app_name> :

```
    "   2020-07-02T11:15:09.21+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] OUT { \"written_at\":\"2020-07-02T05:45:09.210Z\",\"written_ts\":626217332175001,\"tenant_id\":\"-\",\"
component_type\":\"application\",\"component_id\":\"29094be5-e8d6-4467-a230-11cbbb65a25b\",\"space_name\":\"prov_eu10_adev001\",\"component_name\":\"it-
co\",\"component_instance\":\"1\",\"organization_id\":\"3c93940f-0520-423e-a035-780c1c9be4f9\",\"correlation_id\":\"-\",\"organization_name\":\"cpi_adev
001_eu10_org\",\"space_id\":\"75efa1d1-1d35-4c7a-9ba7-df152151990d\",\"container_id\":\"10.0.137.112\",\"type\":\"log\",\"logger\":\"com.company.it.util.loc
k.db.DbLock\",\"thread\":\"app_snapshot_callbackMEDIUM54\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"categories\":[],\"msg\":\"(unlock) Attempting to release lock snapshot-
app-mash-0\" }"
```

We would like to parse the above tail logs into a human-readable format where we are only interested in time and msg.
so the expected output is:

```
2020-07-02T11:15:09.21+0530 (unlock) Attempting to release lock snapshot-app-mash-0
```

cf logs <app_name> | jq 'filter?'

Comment: Take a look at `fromjson` filter in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the input is a valid JSON string, and therefore that invoking jq with the -r option and a filter such as the following should do the trick:

```
capture("^ *(?<date>[^ ]+) [^ ]+ [^ ]+ (?<json>.*)")
| "\(.date) \(.json|fromjson|.msg)"
```

Of course you may need to modify the regex argument of `capture` to match the actual lines in the log file.